# Clone the table while printing in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have one table with some data. If I print this page, I want to print the same table two times side by side. Want to make copy.

[image]

Exactly like this in this image. But in this image datas are different. Its just for sample to show. But my need is same data table sholud come side by side while printing.

[plunkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/pzIfYGIOt7L8eFSJxWlu/)

```css
/* Larger Side Border */
.tb8 {
 width: 230px;
 height:24px;
 border: 1px solid #3366FF;
 border-left: 4px solid #3366FF;
}

.button{
border:4px solid #26759E;-webkit-box-shadow: #878787 0px 2px 2px ;-moz-box-shadow: #878787 0px 2px 2px ; box-shadow: #878787 0px 2px 2px ; -webkit-border-radius: 23px; -moz-border-radius: 23px;border-radius: 23px;font-size:13px;font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif; padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px; text-decoration:none; display:inline-block;text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);font-weight:bold; color: #FFFFFF;
 background-color: #3093C7; background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#3093C7), to(#1C5A85));
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3093C7, #1C5A85);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3093C7, #1C5A85);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3093C7, #1C5A85);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3093C7, #1C5A85);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3093C7, #1C5A85);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#3093C7, endColorstr=#1C5A85);
}

.button:hover{
 border:4px solid #26759E;
 background-color: #26759E; background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#26759E), to(#133D5B));
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #26759E, #133D5B);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #26759E, #133D5B);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #26759E, #133D5B);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #26759E, #133D5B);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #26759E, #133D5B);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#26759E, endColorstr=#133D5B);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Print Directive of html templates </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.printToCart = function(printSectionId) {
        var innerContents = document.getElementById(printSectionId).innerHTML;
        var popupWinindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=600,height=700,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,titlebar=no');
        popupWinindow.document.open();
        popupWinindow.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + innerContents + '</html>');
        popupWinindow.document.close();
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body id="printSectionId" ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>AngularJS Print html templates</h1>
    <form novalidate>
      First Name:
      <input type="text" ng-model="firstName" class="tb8">
      <br>
      <br> Last Name:
      <input type="text" ng-model="lastName" class="tb8">
      <br>
      <br>
      <button ng-click="Submit()" class="button">Submit</button>
      <button ng-click="printToCart('printSectionId')" class="button">Print</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
    <br/>
    <br/><a href="http://www.code-sample.com/2015/07/angularjs-2-forms-validation.html" target="_blank">More About AngularJS Print...</a></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone please tell me if you know the answer.

Comment: you can give `innerContents + innerContents`